# CentOS eth0 not starting

Tags: networking, boot

Why would my new CentOS Virtual Machine not start the interface `eth0` on startup?

I have to start it manually every time.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure `ONBOOT="yes"` is in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.  If you're using NetworkManager, make sure that service starts on boot (`chkconfig NetworkManager on`), otherwise, if you're using the old network service, make sure it starts on boot (`chkconfig network on`).

Answer (score 7):

Regarding CentOS6 not enabling the network interface by default: it (in the GUI installer, at least) does its very best to prevent the interface from being set up properly, but this can be defeated via a checkbox that's hidden a couple dialogs deep from the main flow.

On the screen where you enter the hostname, the "Configure Network" button at the bottom takes you to a "Network Connections" dialog. Select `eth0`, then the "Edit" button takes you to an "Editing System eth0" dialog, which has a "Connect automatically" checkbox. If you leave this box unchecked, you get `ONBOOT="no"` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`; if you check it, you get `ONBOOT="yes"`. I don't know if the checkbox affects any other configs, but I've yet to notice any different behavior. Why the box isn't checked by default, I can't begin to imagine.

Comment: *"it (in the GUI installer, at least) does its very best to prevent the interface from being set up properly"* I laugh because this is painfully true

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could help but I just created the file `/etc/sysconfig/network` with

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=myhostname.mydomain
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
```

And it seems that now my scripts in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` seem to work.